# Splitting a python list into multiple lists

Tags: python

for example, if i have a list like:

`one = [1,2,3]`

what function or method can i use to split each element into their own separate list like:

`one = [1]`

`RANDOM_DYNAMIC_NAME = [2]`

`RANDOM_DYNAMIC_NAME_AGAIN = [3]`

and at any given time, the **unsplit** list called `one` may have more than 1 element, its dynamic, and this algorithm is needed for a hangman game i am coding as self-given homework.

the algorithm is needed to complete this example purpose:

`pick a word: mississippi`

`guess a letter: s`

`['_','_','s','s','_','s','s','_','_','_','_']`

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/gcCZv67D

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea . . . can you clarify how you're hoping to apply this?

Comment: added my code link into pastebin.

yes it sounds like a very bad idea haha, i dont know how else to implement such, im a noob still.

Comment: I would think about having two items - a `guess` (which would be a list of `_`'s equal to the number of letters in the word) and the `word` itself. Then when somebody guesses `s`, find the position of all of the `s`'s in the `word` and replace those same positions with `s` in the `guess`.

Comment: We could probably be more help if you clarified what you're trying to solve - e.g. are you trying to keep track of what's been guessed in each word?  What letters have already been guessed?  Something else?  My suggestion would be to have two variables, one with the literal string, the other that's the same length, but with *'s or something else for unknowns.  Replaces the *'s in the second string as letters are guessed.  No need for dynamic variables, which are generally a bad idea.

Comment: When you think you might need dynamically-generated variables, what you usually _really_ want is a `dict`. But in this case, you don't seem to have any way to ever access the dynamically-generated variables after you create them, so… why create _anything_?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write a hangman solving AI. Look at [my code](https://github.com/inspectorG4dget/Hobby-Coding/blob/master/HobbyCoding/src/Hangman/HangmanV2BKP.py) from a long time ago

Comment: it is for a hangman game, i have coded the game with the most logical sense i currently possess, i have commented the code in the link i have provided where the algorithm should be placed..

thanks.

Comment: hangman solving AI HAHAHA, sorry inspector, im not that experienced with python yet to understand how your code works :) ive only been working with python for 5 months.

Comment: @Vjgaero We can't review your code and explain to you how to solve it.  You'll need to ask some more specific questions, about the particular issue you're having (e.g. tracking what's been guessed, tracking what to show, etc).  You might try also try programmers.stackexchange.com instead, as SO tends to be for specific questions, while programmers tends to be for more general questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, if the part you're trying to solve is the comments in lines 24-26, you definitely don't need dynamically-created variables for that at all, and in fact I can't even imagine how they could help you.

You've got this:

```
enum = [i for i,x in enumerate(letterlist) if x == word]
```

The names of your variables are very confusing—something called `word` is the guessed letter, while you've got a different variable `letterguess` that's something else, and then a variable called `letter` that's the whole word… But I think I get what you're aiming for.

`enum` is a list of all of the indices of `word` within `letterlist`. For example, if `letterlist` is `'letter'` and `word` is `t`, it will be `[2, 3]`.

Then you do this:

```
bracketstrip = (str(w) for w in enum)
```

So now `bracketstrip` is `['2', '3']`. I'm not sure why you want that.

```
z = int(''.join(bracketstrip))
```

And `''.join(bracketstrip)` is `'23'`, so `z` is `23`.

```
letterguess[z] = word
```

And now you get an `IndexError`, because you're trying to set `letterguess[23]` instead of setting `letterguess[2]` and `letterguess[3]`.

Here's what I think you want to replace that with:

```
enum = [i for i,x in enumerate(letterlist) if x == word]
for i in enum:
    letterguess[i] = word
```

A few hints about some other parts of your code:

You've got a few places where you do things like this:

```
letterlist = []
for eachcharacter in letter:
  letterlist.append(eachcharacter)
```

This is the same as `letterlist = list(letter)`. But really, you don't need that list at all. The only thing you do with that is `for i, x in enumerate(letterlist)`, and you could have done the exact same thing with `letter` in the first place. You're generally making things much harder for yourself than you have to. Make sure you actually understand why you've written each line of code.

"Because I couldn't get it to work any other way" isn't a reason—*what* were you trying to get to work? Why did you think you needed a `list` of letters? Nobody can keep all of those decisions in their head at once. The more skill you have, the more of your code will be so obvious to you that it doesn't need comments, but you'll never get to the point where you don't need any. When you're just starting out, every time you figure out how to do something, add a comment reminding yourself what you were trying to do, and why it works. You can always remove comments later; you can never get back comments that you didn't write.

Comment: i didnt think through my project, i just did it a line at a time for the lulz and fun of it, but thanks heaps for your contribution, i will review the code and make some changes, ta :)

Comment: @vjgaero: Well, why did you think you needed dynamic variables here? If even you don't understand what you're trying to do, how do you expect anyone else to tell you how to do it?

Comment: well i couldnt imagine any other way it could happen :( LOL

maybe someone could help me out with a piece of code and id be like AWWWWWWWWWW WHY DIDNT I THINK OF THAT IN THE FIRST PLACE ^.^

Comment: +1 for effort of going through that and points made (+5 if I could)

Comment: thanks, this worked great, really made sense, why didnt i think of this before? ;)

Comment: and for the : letterlist = list(letter) i didnt do that in the first place because i thought it would turn out as a multidimensional list, but that wasnt the case, thanks heaps!!

Comment: @abarnert nice answer, and a nice job trying to explain the idea of breaking things down, and making sure you know the why, instead of just trying to solve the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

for question one ,just list comprehension is good . it will return each element as a separate list

```
[ [x,] for x in one ]
```

Comment: You want `[x]`, not `[x,]`. That's for tuples. (Yes, it's legal to do it this way, but it's bad style, and is only still legal in 3.x to make it easier to generate `literal-eval`-able displays.)

Answer (score -1):

As for a literal answer to your question, here's how you do it, though I can't immagine why you would want to to this. Generally, dynamic variable names are poor design. You probably just want a single list, or list of lists.

```
import random

for x in one:
    name = 'x' + str(random.getrandbits(10))
    globals()[name] = [x]
```

Comment: thanks for the literal answer, although if it 'is' a bad practice, id like someone to provide some insight on how i can implement 'better and more efficient' code into my application that i have provided as a pastebin link, thankyou though!